# iOS: UIButton draw circle border in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton

I need to draw a circle like border outside UIButton. Below is the attach image and code. I also need to show text below button. Following code will add image and text beneath that. But how do I have layer.[image]

```
   UIButton *imageButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [imageButton setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    imageButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    imageButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [imageButton setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    imageButton.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    imageButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans" size:fon];
    [imageButton setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(95, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)];
    [imageButton setTitleColor:[UIColor iconTextColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [imageButton addTarget:target action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: Maybe part of [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/94302/implement-circular-image-loader-animation-cashapelayer) tutorial could help.

Comment: Look into CAShapeLayer and `+[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter: radius: startAngle: endAngle: clockwise: ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
borderView = UIView()

yourButton = UIButton()

borderView.frame.size.width = yourButton.frame.size.width + 1

borderView.layer.cornerRadius = borderView.frame.size.width/2

borderView.clipToBounds = true

borderView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

borderView.layer.borderWidth = 1

borderView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor()
```

Answer (score 2):

set the button  width and height ex : width =100 and height = 100, should be same if you want a round then,

```
imageButton.layer.cornerRadius = 50 // this value should be half from width or height (width = height)
imageButton.layer.masksToBounds = YES
```

//if you want border with above

```
 imageButton.layer.borderWidth = 1;
 imageButton.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
```

Comment: This will not work, since I will get image in circular format previously, I have added text below that image. Now main concern is to add color outside image as drawn in border. This border color is not going to work.

Comment: This would do a 360° outline, not 180° like in the image

Comment: in your case, you cane use `uiview` --> then inside the view (`uiimageview and uilabel`) --->then `unbutton`

Comment: @ Dopapp yes absolutely right, how can we work on this, since after adding text below uibutton, its give 360° border color

Comment: why can't you use image with the border